# Check table existence in slick 3.0

Tags: database, scala, slick-3.0

How do you check if a table exists with slick 3.0?

There was a way in previous versions of slick by using:

```scala
MTable.getTables.list()
```

But this doesn't compile anymore.

The idea behind this question is to dynamically create a table when it doesn't exists, pretty much like this:

```scala
if (Tables.contains("USERS") == false)
    Users.createTable()
```

Comment: Try db.run(Mtable.getTables)  which will return a Future

Comment: The db.run call did it. I forgot that everything is a DBIO in slick 3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Slick 3.0 `MTable.getTables` is a `DBAction` which was to be run via a `Database` instance:

```
val tables = Await.result(db.run(MTable.getTables), 1.seconds).toList
```

Of course, you should probable deal with the `Future` returned by `db.run` in an asynchronous manner (via `map` or *for-comprehension*) rather than blocking on it as I did for the example.

Comment: is toList method call supported by that query?

Comment: The return value of `MTable.getTables` is a stream which is an implementation of `Seq` hence you can get a list by calling the function `toList` because every implementation of `Seq` needs to implement a `toList` function